# What does: First professional experience within a Consultancy mean?

Tags: applications

While looking at Consultant vacancies I saw this line: "First professional experience within a Consultancy" as one of the listed qualifications.

This is so vague. Do they mean that they want someone with previous Consultancy experience with only 1 company?

Edited: Added information below.

Here is an except from their listed "Desired Qualifications":

- Above-average degree in Engineering or Science
- First professional experience within a  Consultancy
- Analytical and strategic mindset
- High communication skills
- Ability to work independently as well as in a team...

So do they want someone with consulting experience or not? I have tried HR on multiple days at different times. No one ever answers. :/

Emails have also been ignored. I only sent 2 because I didn't want to seem like I was pestering them.

Guess this is a sign to not apply...:D

Comment: It could also at a pinch mean that your first "professional experience" (i.e. real job) was at a consultancy, or they could be saying that this job should be your first experience within a consultancy, i.e. you shouldn't have been a consultant anywhere else. I think you'd have to contact them and ask.

Comment: To me it is "Never having been a consultant before" which sets off all kind of red flags.  Are they counting on inexperience to take advantage?  But like anything else doesn't hurt to respond and ask.

Comment: Need context. Could be asking applicants to tell the company when their first ... was.

Comment: Like many other vacancy descriptions, they are kinda vague. I will edit my original post to include more of the listed "Qualifications"

Answer (score 2):

This would be purely company specific, it's not a common requirement. Since you can't contact HR to actually ask them. I suggest you move along and avoid anything to do with them.

Being unable to contact HR on multiple ocassions is enough of a red flag for me.